# Rails refactor form view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have rails app with conditions according to `params`

```
# _search.html.slim

.search.text-center.my-5
  .container
    -if params[:city_slug]
      = form_tag(city_jobs_path(city_slug: params[:city_slug]), method: :get, class: "form-inline") do
        .row
          .col-md-8.mb-md-0.no-padding
            = search_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: 'Find a job (name, company, position)', class: 'form-control rounded-left no-border-radius bg-light h-100'
          .col-md-2.mb-md-0.no-padding
            = select_tag(:salary,
                       options_for_select( @salary_range.collect {|s| [vnd_format(s), s]},
                                           params[:salary] ), 
                                           class:"form-select bg-light h-100")      
          .col-md-2.mb-md-0.no-padding
            = submit_tag "Search", class: "h-100 w-100 btn btn-block btn-lg btn-info"

    -elsif params[:industry_slug]
       = form_tag(industry_jobs_path(industry_slug: params[:industry_slug]), method: :get, class: "form-inline") do
        .row
          .col-md-8.mb-md-0.no-padding
            = search_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: 'Find a job (name, company, position)', class: 'form-control rounded-left no-border-radius bg-light h-100'
          .col-md-2.mb-md-0.no-padding
            = select_tag(:salary,
                       options_for_select( @salary_range.collect {|s| [vnd_format(s), s]},
                                           params[:salary] ), 
                                           class:"form-select bg-light h-100")     
          .col-md-2.mb-md-0.no-padding
            = submit_tag "Search", class: "h-100 w-100 btn btn-block btn-lg btn-info"

    - else 
      = form_tag(jobs_path, method: :get, class: "form-inline") do
        .row
          .col-md-4.mb-md-0.no-padding
            = search_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: 'Find a job (name, company, position)', class: 'form-control rounded-left no-border-radius bg-light h-100'
          .col-md-2.mb-md-0.no-padding
            = select_tag(:city,
                       options_for_select( @city_slug_list,
                                           params[:city] ), 
                                           include_blank: 'Select city',
                                           class:"form-select bg-light h-100")
          .col-md-2.mb-md-0.no-padding
            = select_tag(:industry,
                       options_for_select( @industry_slug_list,
                                           params[:industry] ), 
                                           include_blank: 'Select city',
                                           class:"form-select bg-light h-100")
          .col-md-2.mb-md-0.no-padding
            = select_tag(:salary,
                       options_for_select( @salary_range.collect {|s| [vnd_format(s), s]},
                                           params[:salary] ), 
                                           include_blank: 'Select salary',
                                           class:"form-select bg-light h-100")
          
          .col-md-2.mb-md-0.no-padding
            = submit_tag "Search", class: "h-100 w-100 btn btn-block btn-lg btn-info"
```

Overall, they look similar. Only the path is different, is there any way to refactor this code

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to fix [DRY](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%E2%80%99t_repeat_yourself) here is to extract common erb-code to partial and render it from every template with:

```
<%= render partial: 'search_fields' %>
```

Also your can make your partial more universal with passing some options ith there with locals:

```
<%= render partial: 'search_fields', locals: { industries: false } %>
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

### BTW

It is not a good practice to access to `params` object inside views because it is a controller level. This way your code becomes too [coupled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)). It is better to pass required values to instance variables.

Also you can use [PageObject](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/PageObject.html) pattern to make your code more maintainable.